# Determine $\frac{dz}{dt}$ at the point where (s,t) = (2,1)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am solving this problem for Lon Capa. It is an online website where they give me questions and I have to solve the answer and then type it in. Sometimes my answers are correct and I'm just typing it in wrong. I'm wondering if that is the case here?

Let

$$
z(x,y)= e^{y/x}
$$
$$
x(s,t)=\sqrt{14-s^2-t^2}
$$
$$
y(s,t) = sln(t)
$$

I solved for $\frac{dz}{dt}$ and got $\frac{tye^{y/x}}{x^2\sqrt(14-s^2-t^2)}$ + $\frac{se^{y/x}}{xt}$

The program says that this is correct. The next question said to determine $\frac{dz}{dt}$ at the point where (s,t) = (2,1). That just means I have to plug in that point into the equation I got for $\frac{dz}{dt}$ right? Once I did that I got $\frac{ye^{y/x}}{3x^2} + \frac{2e^{y/x}}{x}$ However, it was labeled inocrrect. I was hoping someone would explain this problem to me or would check my work and see if my work is correct.

Comment: Note that $x$ and $y$ are determined. You did not compute them.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Small oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far looks correct.  What you overlooked is that $x$ and $y$ are also functions of $s$ and $t$.  Find $x(2,1)$ and $y(2,1)$ and plug those in for a numerical answer.